# Is it correct to drop #include <stdio.h> in C?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

If I use `printf`, `scanf`, `puts` or some other function in C (not C++) and don't write an include line, can it be treated as unspecified or undefined behaviour?

As I remember, C didn't require porotope declaration at all, but it was recommended to have them to allow compiler to make type casts on calling. And prototypes for `printf` and other such functions are not required still, not sure about custom functions.

PS: This question relates to discussion in comments of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55989/32091.

Comment: How you could compile a code with those function without includes?

Comment: "C didn't require porotope declaration at all" - that's antique/medieval C. Since 1989, declarations are required (and calling a variadic function without it being declared as variadic is UB in particular.) But why would you want to do this anyway?

Comment: @LPs, easy: http://codepad.org/m4DB2Ndd - even no warnings from gcc.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant as I recall however, C does sometimes compile well and finds the function prototype anyway even if it returns a warning about implicit function declaration

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant, there is a link to code golf in the question. Dropping this line will make the code 18 chars less. Also, it's strang when some solutions have it and the others don't.

Comment: If you really have to (shortening program or quine), it will work, of course. But no matter what, you should include header files at all.

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski that may be a compiler extension. I don't consider that "C".

Comment: @Qwertiy **Codepad** doesn't show any warnings. Compiling it in my computer with `-Wall -pedantic` gives **lots** of warnings. So, gcc does give warnings.

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski, I'm asking about concrete functions from cstdio. Not sure, but I think they have some special behaviour and exactly this unclude can be skipped, not any include in C.

Comment: @Qwertiy well, that's too bad. It makes the program incorrect. You could as well remove every character by that logic. Sure, it makes the program incorrect, but LOOK, ZERO CHARS!!!

Comment: @MichałSzydłowski "it will work, of course" – not quite "of course". It may work. But it may not because it's undefined behavior.

Comment: Ok, but impossible with printf(). Without include stdio.h you get implicit declaration warning.

Comment: @Qwertiy: By the way, I knew that this kind of discussion will start in the moment I had seen the link you gave me was for SO ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it correct to drop #include  in C?

No, it's not correct. Always include it if you use a `stdio.h` function like `printf`.

C has removed implicit declarations (with C99) and the includes are required. The only other alternative is to have a visible prototyped declaration for `printf`.

Moreover even when C had implicit declarations, implicit declarations are not OK for variable argument functions; so in C89 not adding a `stdio.h` include and not having a visible prototype (for `printf` example) is undefined behavior.

Comment: When has it been removed?

Comment: @Zaibis in my answer I put *"The only other alternative is to have a visible prototyped declaration for printf."*

Comment: @ouah - To be admittedly pedantic, variable argument functions use the same mechanism for passing arguments that functions without a prototype use: argument promotion.  In fact, it wouldn't surprise me if one of the main drivers in the development of variable argument syntax for C was to shoehorn existing library functions such as `open()` with it's optional `mode` argument into having a prototype.

Answer (score 2):

For professional development, no.

For codegolfing, it is ok.

If you don't declare a function, the compiler automatically generates one, which may or may not match its real declaration. If it doesn't, it may or may not produce segfault or a software bug. `gcc` also gives in this case a warning.

Comment: The question was not about professional development - in that case I agree with you. But are you absolutely sure that functions from stdio are not the special case according to the standart?

Comment: @Qwertiy I don't close out, but I see it highly improbable, because it is a language thing, and isn't about the standard library.

Comment: On the fly I would assume that since the standard only is talking about the enviroment has to provide this functions but system and compiler could both be considered as enviroment by that phrasing, so both are providing it but the OS has higher priority. (but if you look in i.e. the install dir of gcc you will find in it own implementations as header files, which are for that case but it may or not may warn about it since it may also be considered as enviroment and also the standard states its functionality has to be as: ...." But -> its just a on the fly assumption.

Comment: No, it's not OK.  Arguments to calls made to functions without a prototype will be promoted, and unless the function is defined in a way where such promotion is expected, the arguments the function sees will not match the arguments passed by the caller, unless all arguments don't need to be promoted.  Since library functions expect the arguments **not** to be promoted, it's not OK to omit the header in the calling code.

Answer (score 1):

**No** and **Yes**

`stdio.h` has an **explicit** declaration of the functions you want to use, such things are prohibited if it was a C++ compiler (g++ for example).
Since c++ requires **explicit** declarations of all functions, but any proper `C compiler` will create an **implicit** declaration of those functions, compile the code into object file, and when linked with the standard library, it will find a definition of those functions that accidentally will match the implicit declaration, probably `gcc` will give you a warning.

So if you are writing software that you want to be maintainable and readable, that's not an option to drop it, however for fast prototyping or code challenges, this might not be that important.

Comment: "might not be that important"?  Try calling something basic like `malloc()` in an LP64 environment without including the proper header....

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can skip `#include` in many cases. But for some functions the compiler cannot generate correct function call without prototype. E.g. if a parameter is `double` and you put `0` - with prototype it will be converted and stored as `double` value in stack and otherwise there will be `int` which will produce wrong calculations.

Comment: I understand this. But is there anything explicit in standart about it?

Comment: First standard of C says that without prototype the function is assumed `int func( void )` (if remember correcty). I.e. no prototype only when there are no parameters.